# neo4j Java API Time complexity of getRelationships method

Tags: java, performance, scala, neo4j

It's not said in documentation what complexity have methods which return iterator (or I've missed it).

Let's say I'm looking for a specific type, so i execute this:

`node.getRelationships(RelType)`

And I have three scenarios:

> node has:
>
> 1) ~100k relations, where half of them has type RelType
>
> 2) ~1M relations, where half of them has type RelType
>
> 2) ~1M relations, where 50k has type RelType

Does it affect time required to **return an iterator**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Neo4j 2.1.x all of those should have the same characteristics.

Als relationships for nodes with more than (50 or 100) rels are stored in a structure by type and direction, it is directly accessing and loading the structure.

For the first access that relationship-chain has to be loaded from disk, for subsequent accesses it will be available in memory.